# ksoap services accessing by maximum user and it crashes or not?

Tags: soap, n-tier-architecture, ksoap

I want to clear my doubt.am using ksoap services and it work successfully.but if multiple user accessing at a time for example 1000+ user are accessing then it will crashes or not.in three tier architecture if 1 of the layer crashes by server load it impact to another.like flip-kart or amazon are crashes when multiple user accessing at a time.so i want to clear my point.how to recover this problem?if anybody have an idea please clear my point and if any problem how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

we have no idea if it crashes or not under 1k+ users load. we don't know you setting and architecture. you have to do load tests and check it.

what happens it 1 layer crashes? it depends on what does it mean. it you mean 'exception will be thrown' the usually http servers handle this without any problems. they catch the exception, return error and are ready to handle another connection. but if there will be not enough memory or a segfault then whole runtime goes down. if other layers are handled by the same runtime then they go down as well.

how to make you application more resilient? depending on your budget and needs: separate, replicate, monitor and auto-scale. for example: keep different layers on different machines, keep multiple copy of the same service on different machines, working at the same time. have software (like mesos) that keeps required number of your services running (if some service goes down, the software will launch new instance of the service on new machine). use cloud to automatically use more machines when you have higher load.